# How to use a private number from other class in Java

Tags: java, variables, methods

hi i have two classes.

```
class Table
{
    private int number = 20;

    //here i have some methods...

   public int getNumber(){
       return number;
   }
}
```

I also have this method:

```
class Basic
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Table table = new Table();
        //here i declare my variables
        while(score > table.getNumber()){
            //do work
        }
    }
}
```

i have a problem in while. i put a print to see the table.getNumber and is always 0. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There's something you're not telling us - from my point of view, `number` is always 20.

Comment: prove it to us. Show a minimal working example of all your code (which should be easy for you to make here) that we can copy, paste into a new file, run javac, and then run java, and see that your code indeed generates that. Usually while you're making that file for people, you actually discover the problem all on your own and never end up needing to ask online.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to what you are setting

For example: if you have some setter in your `Table` class and call it manually or auto

Like next:

```
class Table
{
    private int number = 20;

    //here i have some methods...

   public int getNumber(){
       return number;
   }

   public void setNumber(int number){
      this.number = number;
   }
}
```

....

```
   table.setNumber(0);
```

Or, some meta-programming (using reflection)

Like

```
    Table table = new Table();
    Field field  = table.getClass().getDeclaredField("number");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(table, 0);
    System.out.println(field.get(table));
```

Also, there are some tricks with `Unsafe` but if you set int to 20 and try to get you will receive 20, for better/clear test try to add `final` to `number` field like next:

```
class Table
{
    private final int number = 20;

    //here i have some methods...

   public int getNumber(){
       return number;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just ran the following code:

```
class Basic {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Table table = new Table();
        System.out.println(table.getNumber());
    }
}
```

With output:

```
20
```

So there's something wrong with how you're running this. Try starting from scratch in a new directory.